Vue component is not working properly, can i do this?
I'm trying to add a template tag with attributes and values nut it keeps displaying this error message
<script> </script> <template> <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary"> <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
Component name "Navigation" should always be multi-word.
I couldn't try anything

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You want to refer to the Navigation component by adding a template tag. You can use the following template for this:


<template id="navigation-template">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>



In this line of code, we used the  element. <directive in template element HTML, a pointer to the HTML it contains>. This code must be loaded via JavaScript to be accessed by the browser.
If you want to use the Navigation component, you need to access it via JavaScript:


// Using JavaScript template element loading
const navigationTemplate = document.getElementById('navigation-template');
const navigationContent = document.importNode(navigationTemplate.content, true);

// Add a loaded "navigation" element to the app
document.body.appendChild(navigationContent);



In this JavaScript code, document.getElementById('navigation-template') selects the <template> element by product. The <template> HTML is converted to browser-readable HTML using the document.import node() function, then appended to the page using document.body.appendChild().
This method hides the markup through HTML and JavaScript and gives you support for naming the "Navigation" component.
